# How to create Python (2.7.3) RPM package?

Tags: python, rpm

No matter what I try, I cannot do this. I'm on Centos 5.6 x86_64

1 `python setup.py bdist_rmp` gives me syntax error:

```
[root@localhost Python-2.7.3]# python setup.py bdist_rpm
  File "setup.py", line 361
    with open(tmpfile) as fp:
```

2 `checkinstall python setup.py install` outputs the same syntax error as above.

3 `checkinstall make install` and has a lot of `ignoring ...` statements in the stdout and the final RPM doesn't have most of files.

4 Using [this shell script](https://github.com/scalp42/python-2.7.x-on-Centos-5.x/blob/master/install_python27.sh) I can get python installed and build the RPM package with `python setup.py bdist_rpm` method, however, the python 2.7 package will require python 2.7 as it's dependency.

**EDIT**: Actually, no, the #4 doesn't work either.

I tired different `./configure --prefix` values, none of them made any difference.

I've read many options how to install python on Centos, but 99% of suggesting using plain 'make install' which I need to avoid.

Thanks in advance.

### EDIT

I was able to package it with this command:

```
checkinstall --fstrans=no --install=no --pkgname=python --pkgversion "2.7.3" --default
```

However, when I try to install it with `rpm -i` I get this:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    libtcl8.4.so()(64bit) is needed by python-2.7.3-1.x86_64
    libtk8.4.so()(64bit) is needed by python-2.7.3-1.x86_64
python < 2.4.3-32.el5 conflicts with python-libs-2.4.3-44.el5.x86_64
```

The missing dependency are understandable, however it's one obvious what's in conflict and how to resolve it.

Comment: Your error message is incomplete. Please paste the entire message.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thank you for your interest. However, it is indeed the full error message i get for `python setup.py bdist_rmp` command. Also I got some progress with `checkinstall`, but now I'm stuck with conflict problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing with your local system packages trying to build this, I would suggest you look at using [Fedora's Mock](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Projects/Mock). Regarding the conflicts you're getting take a look at the requires for python 2.4 using:

```
rpm -qR python (and the version if it is not the system release)
```

It's probably just that Python 2.4 requires an older version of python-libs.